# How to access to widgets properties in a Gtk+ 3 / Glade / Python 3 project

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk3, glade

I use the classical code [example](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/builder.html#glade-and-gtk-builder) :

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

class Handler():

    def onDeleteWindow(self, *args):
        Gtk.main_quit(*args)

    def on_button1_clicked(self, button):
        print("Hello World!")

builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file("D:/temp/test1.glade")
builder.connect_signals(Handler())

window = builder.get_object("window1")
window.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

And all is OK. But :

- How to change a widget property in event. Like change the button1 label on click on it. Mainly because in the event is in Handler which does'nt see window ?
- Where/how to have all the Python/Gtk informations about widgets, like widgets properties names (ie : what is the label property of a GtkButton ?) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where/how to have all the Python/Gtk informations about widgets, like widgets properties names?

https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0

> How to change a widget property in event. Like change the button1 label on click on it.

```
button.set_label()
```

https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Button.html#Gtk.Button.set_label

Comment: Thx for the first link. For the second, when I code button1.set_label() in on_button1_clicked event it doesn't work because button1 is not known in Handler.

Comment: You named the argument `button` in the callback.

Comment: Sorry but I am noob in Python, your answer about callback is not very clear. Any example ?

Comment: def on_button1_clicked(self, button):
        button.set_label("somthing")
        print("Hello World!")

Comment: But with the correct indentation of course. (Can't ident in comments)

Comment: @matan7890  It was clear for me to access to the button properties in the button events. But not how to access to the other objects properties.